# React native live search request with parameter cannot show on FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

Here I am having a very difficult time displaying data with certain parameter requests.

constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      search: '',
      query: '',
      isFetching: false,
      spinner: false,
    };
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
  }
```

componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.handleBackButtonClick,
    );
    this.setState(this.fetchAll(''))
  }
```

URL API:

```
    this.setState({
      spinner: !this.state.spinner
    });
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    const xtx = api.url('master/item/consumables')+`?search=${search}&page=${this.state.page}`
    await axios.get(api.url('master/item/consumables')+`?search=${search}&page=${this.state.page}`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + value,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(xtx + ' yaya');
      this.setState({
        data: this.state.data.concat(response.data.data.data),
      });
      this.setState({
        spinner: !this.state.spinner,
      });
      this.setState({ isFetching: false })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({
        spinner: !this.state.spinner,
      });
      this.setState({error: error});
    });
  };
```

Form Search:

```
            style={{flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10, color: '#444444'}}
            placeholder={'Cari...'}
            placeholderTextColor={'#999999'}
            onChangeText={(search) => this.fetchAll({search})}
            // onSubmitEditing={(search) => this.onRefresh()}
          />
```

can you tell me the correct one or is there any other reference. Thank you.

[image]